# Reverse strings in C

Tags: c, string

What's the problem with the following code?

```
#define N 30
int main() {
    char str[N], new_str[N];
    int i,len;
    printf("Please enter 20 letters. \n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    len = strlen(str);
    printf("The length of str is  %d ", len);
    for (i=0; i< len; i++)
        new_str[i]=str[len-1-i];
    printf("The result is: %s\n", new_str);
    return 1;
}
```

I checked that for every string under 16 characters the program is OK, and above it returns undefined characters at the end:

```
  Please enter 20 letters.
  1234567891111111

  The result is: 1111111987654321q=V?.
```

However, if I initialize `str, new_str` with "" the problem is solved. I still I wonder what causes the problem.

Comment: You have to add the \0 character for the new_str like new_str[i]= '\0' after the for loop completes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the null terminator:

```
new_str[len] = '\0';
```

otherwise, there is garbage after the last character, so the string is not ending

Comment: Isn't it being add automatically when I enter a string?

Comment: to the first string, but strlen returns the length without the null terminator.

Comment: @Numerator: At `new_str`? Why should it? You are not inputting it, you are inputting `str`.

Comment: strlen(str) doesn't take into account the null terminator. You are working on the characters of the string **not including** the null terminator.

Comment: @dda: and even if it _were_ included, reversing would put the terminator to the _beginning_. :-)

Comment: So since '\0' is being puted,  all the rest 10 "garbage" characters will be printed as well when I use printf?

Comment: Note that the `\0` is added by many string functions too; `strcpy`, `strcat` and so on. And with constant assignments like `const char* s = "string";` But not when manipulating the individual chars in the string manually!

Comment: printf will print only the characters before the '\0', as `%s` indicates string, and string in C is defined as char buffer up until `\0`.

Comment: So where exactly should I add the Null terminator?

Comment: @Numerator And if you have `new_str[30]` and you fill all its 30 chars with non-zero values, printf will not stop after printing 30 chars! It will continue printing garbage until it encounters a `\0`!!

Comment: @Numerator You should put the null terminator at the end, like Binyamin says in the answer.

Comment: oh! I see, thanks! how come the code is fine to less than 16 characters? Null pointer wasn't puted as well.

Comment: @numerator: probably fluke, there could be 1 or more nul characters in the uninitialized contents of `new_str`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add a null terminator to your new_str or printf doesn't know when to stop. Alternatively you could reverse the string *in situ*, like this.

```
char s[] = "StackOverflow";
size_t l = strlen(s);
int i, j, k;
k = l/2;
// Work with half the length
for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
  // swap the two bytes
  j=s[i];
  s[i]=s[l-1-i];
  s[l-1-i]=j;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys :-) I wanted the fastest reverse possible. But this code would break like glass in a kindergarten juggling contest if you used it on 2-byte+ encodings :-)

Comment: @dda: well, so does the copying variant of reversing as well. Indeed, utf-8 and the like are a completely different story: such "strings" shouldn't be called "strings" and should IMHO  be processed only with a special library (maybe self-made), manual processing is too error-prone. (Perhaps someone knows such a library for C?)

Comment: @Vlad ehm, why should UTF-8 encoded strings not be called strings?

Comment: Well, because of many reasons. For example: saying `s++` doesn't shift you to the next char; `strlen(s)` doesn't give you the true length; [not every non-NULL character is valid at arbitrary position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences).

Comment: @Vlad For serious business purposes, [IBM's ICU library](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/) is what you need. Maybe a bit of overkill for simple stuff like this though.

Comment: I agree with @Vlad. UTF-8 strings are byte arrays where each element is of variable length. To get the next char, you need to look at each byte and depending on its value add it to the pile, or keep going.

Comment: More readable with  
`for (i=0,m=l-1; i<k; i++,m--) {
     j=s[i];
   s[i]=s[m];
   s[m]=j;
        }`

Comment: FWIW, I'd probably write it `for (char *left = s, *right = s + l - 1; left < right; ++left, --right) { char tmp = *left; *left = *right; *right = tmp; }`. Only with more line breaks. It has a drawback that behavior is undefined when `l` is 0, which in this case it isn't but in general you can special-case.

Answer (score 2):

Strings should be zero-terminated. After the scanf, `str` is, but `new_str` hasn't been given a value, so it still contains garbage. After the loop, the first (20?) characters have been set, but you still need to append a `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

`new_str` is not NUL terminated.

After you have copied all the characters from `str`, you need to add a '\0' to the end of `new_str` like this:

```
new_str[i] = '\0';
```